# I need to pullback data from a jquery ajax post and break the array out to seperate outputs

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to get the array and instead of just pushing the data into an html div - get back the php variable.

My $.ajax post ----

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("#login").click(function() {
            var theName = $.trim($("#username").val());

            if(theName.length > 0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "callajaxdemo.php",
                  data: ({name: theName}),
                  cache: false,
                  dataType: "text",
                  success: onSuccess
                });
            }
        });

        $("#resultLog").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
          $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + settings.url + "<br />HTTP Code: " + request.status);
        });

        function onSuccess(data)
        {
            $("#resultLog").html("Result: " + data);
            //$.mobile.changePage('stats.html', { transition: 'slideup'}, true, true);
        }

    });
</script>'
```

My PHP file is -----

```
<?php
 $username = $_POST['username']; 
 $password = $_POST['password'];

$host = 'https://api.qpme.com/api/accounts/me';

$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($process);

$content = json_decode($return);

/*
echo "<pre>";
print_r($content);
echo "</pre>";
*/

print $content->email . "<br>";
print "<h3>" . "Welcome" . ' ' . $content->firstName . ' ' . $content->lastName . '!' . "<h3>";

?>'
```

The goal would be to get back the array and then post certain parts of it to different jquery mobile pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send JSON data back to AJAX request.

Change your arrays to JSON like this:

```
echo json_encode($yourData);
```

To read this, you have to setup your script to accept JSON data

```
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "callajaxdemo.php",
          data: ({name: theName}),
          cache: false,
          dataType: "json", // <--- Here
          success: onSuccess
        });
```

Then you can access the properties as JavaScript Object.

```
    function onSuccess(data)
    {
        // access using data.item1
        //           or data.item2 how you prepare your array
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked - it's still weird to me that the data passed turns into PHP post variables even though it is passed through json format - I guess that is the JQUERY doing the work?

Comment: @Ezos, Great. Yeah the parameter are sent as POST variables. I think you should accept my answer then.

Comment: Thanks again for your help - I have a great example here: https://codenvy.com/factory?v=1.0&pname=Jquery-Postback-Example&wname=ecavazos&vcs=git&vcsurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcodenvy.com%2Fgit%2F48%2Fe7%2Fdc%2Fworkspaceu909ru5xicwtsrnx%2FJquery-Postback-Example&idcommit=a5e069a4e35a0a70a45075224f3d4f604793fb9b&action=openproject&ptype=PHP&openfile=index.php

This will instantly launch an ide and you can hit run and see a working example. :)